# Uploaded images appear to save, then disappear later

Tags: ruby-on-rails, image, ruby-on-rails-4, paperclip

I'm using Rails 4 to build a blog. Each blog post has an image, title and text. I can upload an image, see that the image is there when I look at the posts/:id page, but later when I go back to that same page the image is gone. I'm using the Paperclip gem for rails 4.

Is my image tied to a session somehow? Is it not really saving to the database? Here is a link to the deployed project with the image that doesn't show up: https://vinna.herokuapp.com/posts/1

I'm still learning, so any information is greatly appreciated!

Here is my controller:

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
def index
    @posts = Post.all
end

def new
    @post = Post.new
end

def create
    @post = Post.new(post_params)

    if @post.save
        redirect_to @post
    else
        render 'new'
    end
end

def show
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])
end

def edit
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])
end

def update
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])

    if @post.update(post_params)
        redirect_to @post
    else
        render 'edit'
    end
end

def destroy
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])
    @post.destroy

    redirect_to posts_path
end

private
    def post_params
        params.require(:post).permit(:image, :title, :text)
    end
end
```

My model:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
has_many :comments
has_attached_file :image, styles: { small: "100x100", med: "200x200", large: "600x600"}

validates :title, presence: true,
                                    length: { minimum: 2 }

validates :text, presence: true,
                                    length: { minimum: 2 }

validates_attachment_presence :image
validates_attachment_size :image, :less_than => 5.megabytes
validates_attachment_content_type :image, :content_type => ['image/jpeg', 'image/png']
end
```

My migrations:

```
class CreatePosts < ActiveRecord::Migration
def change
create_table :posts do |t|
  t.string :title
  t.text :text

  t.timestamps null: false
end
end
end
```

And adding paperclip:

```
class AddPaperclipToPost < ActiveRecord::Migration
def change
add_attachment :posts, :image
end
end
```

And part of my view from posts/:id

```
    <p class="blog-photo_large"><%= link_to image_tag(@post.image.url(:large)), @post.image.url %></p>
```

Comment: You'll probably need to set up AWS S3 account check this https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/paperclip-s3

Comment: Seconding @Cyzanfar, had this exact problem and used S3 to solve.

Answer (score 3):

This should work fine on single machine. However using heroku your app should be a 12-factor-app. In this case you shouldn't be using the Filesystem but an additional service for storing files. This is because the app code on heroku is distributed across multiple physical hardware instances and your never know which actual node will be responding to https://vinna.herokuapp.com/posts/1. So your first see the image on some particular node and then your are loadbalanced to some other which does not have it stored.

See point IV of [The Twelve-Factor-App](http://12factor.net/backing-services).